# What does PYTHONUNBUFFERED in Dockerfile do?

Tags: python, django, docker, dockerfile

I'm just getting started with docker, and I've been seeing a `PYTHONUNBUFFERED` environment variable in every Dockerfile for python. Can anyone kindly explain what it actually is?

Comment: https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/issues/319

Comment: check this out:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59812009/what-is-the-use-of-pythonunbuffered-in-docker-file/59812588

Comment: Force the stdout and stderr streams to be unbuffered. This option has no effect on the stdin stream.

https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html

Setting PYTHONUNBUFFERED to a non empty value ensures that the python output is sent straight to terminal (e.g. your container log) without being first buffered and that you can see the output of your application (e.g. django logs) in real time.

This also ensures that no partial output is held in a buffer somewhere and never written in case the python application crashes.