# AWS : Cloudwatch logs only published after Batch job is completed

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-batch

I am using a AWS Batch job , which triggers an ECR Image ( Docker Image containing python code) and the batch logs to Cloudwatch.

As per the code inside Docker, I am using print command to log as shown below. The issue is all the print statements are shown in the CloudWatch only when the Batch is completed, which takes around 2-3 hours to complete.

The prints are not logged as per code executes, instead all prints are shown only when the whole process completes. Is there a way we can flush the print as soon as the line executes.

Does the CloduWatch/Batch store the logs in memory and flushes only when the job is completed?

Python Code:

```py
print("Process Started..")
#some code 
print("Process Completed.")
```

Comment: I see the same thing, the timestamps of the logs are all within 2 seconds of each other, despite the job taking ~10 minutes in my case.

Comment: Over [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/CloudWatch-Agent-Configuration-File-Details.html) there is mention of the `force_flush_interval` configuration property for the CloudWatch Logs Agent in `/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/etc/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.json` logs section.  Perhaps this can be set / adjusted.

Comment: You need to use a logger for logging the output. In java, I use SLF4j to log and it outputs the value while running and can see the logs while job is running for hours or even days .

Comment: When I used `print` it logged only after the job was completed/terminated, replaced with `logging` in python and it logs whilst the job is running. Thanks @AasthaJain

Comment: @suraj You are welcome. Glad I could help .

Answer (score 0):

You can add the environment variable `PYTHONUNBUFFERED` to your Dockerfile:

```bash
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
```

This will assure that the Python output is sent straight to your log instead of being buffered.

You can read more about `PYTHONUNBUFFERED` here:

- [Python Documentation > Command line and environment > PYTHONUNBUFFERED](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONUNBUFFERED)
- [Stack Overflow > What is the use of PYTHONUNBUFFERED in docker file?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59812588/10917711)