# Why does my docker containers freezed up?

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile, mqtt, mosquitto

I've created 3 containers:

1. A container for publishing messages on MQTT protocol every second using
   python paho-mqtt
2. A subscriber container
3. A mosquitto server container

Container creation commands:

```
docker image build -t publisher /path/to/dockerfile folder

docker image build -t subscriber /path/to/dockerfile folder
```

Publisher container docker file:

```
FROM python:3.9.7

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 1883

COPY . .

CMD [ "python", "app.py" ]
```

And this is mosquitto container log, that shows it runs properly:

```
1658502881: mosquitto version 2.0.14 running
1658502881: New connection from 172.17.0.5:53757 on port 1883.
1658502881: New client connected from 172.17.0.5:53757 as python-mqtt-29 (p2, c1, k60).
1658502881: New connection from 172.17.0.4:45437 on port 1883.
1658502881: New client connected from 172.17.0.4:45437 as python-mqtt-12 (p2, c1, k60).
```

Apparently, everything looks good but The problem is when I run the publisher and subscriber containers (`docker run publisher`), the terminal app freezes up for about 2,3 minutes and then all the messages show up after that delay.

[image: My running containers]

[image: My publish and subscribe containers after 2,3 minutes]

Again pub and sub containers freeze up for 2,3 minutes.

Could anyone help me with that?

---

Update:

My publisher app

```
import random
import time
from paho.mqtt import client as mqtt_client

broker = '172.17.0.3'
port = 1883
topic = "python/mqtt"

client_id = f'python-mqtt-{random.randint(0, 1000)}'

def connect_mqtt():
    def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
        if rc == 0:
            print("Connected to MQTT Broker!")
        else:
            print("Failed to connect, return code %d\n", rc)

    client = mqtt_client.Client(client_id)
    client.on_connect = on_connect
    client.connect(broker, port)
    return client

def publish(client):
    msg_count = 0
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        msg = f"messages: {msg_count}"
        result = client.publish(topic, msg)
        # result: [0, 1]
        status = result[0]
        if status == 0:
            print(f"Send `{msg}` to topic `{topic}`")
        else:
            print(f"Failed to send message to topic {topic}")
        msg_count += 1

def run():
    client = connect_mqtt()
    client.loop_start()
    publish(client)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

My subscriber:

```
import random
import pandas
from paho.mqtt import client as mqtt_client

broker = '172.17.0.3'
port = 1883
topic = "python/mqtt"
client_id = f'python-mqtt-{random.randint(0, 100)}'


def connect_mqtt() -> mqtt_client:
    def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
        if rc == 0:
            print("Connected to MQTT Broker!")
        else:
            print("Failed to connect, return code %d\n", rc)

    client = mqtt_client.Client(client_id)
    client.on_connect = on_connect
    client.connect(broker, port)
    return client


def subscribe(client: mqtt_client):
    def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
        print(f"Received `{msg.payload.decode()}` from `{msg.topic}` topic")

    client.subscribe(topic)
    client.on_message = on_message


def run():
    client = connect_mqtt()
    subscribe(client)
    client.loop_forever()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

Comment: Edit the question to include the code for the subscriber /publisher apps

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Do [the answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59812009/11810946) provide an answer? (in short: add `ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1` to your `dockerfile` to resolve the issue).

Comment: `ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1` solved the problem. Thank you Brits.