# Basic Logging in kubernetes through python

Tags: python, kubernetes, logging

I have do a logging example

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: counter
spec:
  containers:
  - name: count
    image: busybox:1.28
    args: [/bin/sh, -c,
            'i=0; while true; do echo "$i: $(date)"; i=$((i+1)); sleep 1; done']
```

to create this counter

```
kubectl apply -f counter.yaml
```

to get logs

```
kubectl logs counter
```

taken from : [Kubernetes logging example](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/)
how ever when i tried the same with python `print` or `stdout.write` its not working

Comment: if i add `-u` in container command to run python counter its working fine

Answer (score 1):

Python by default buffers its output to `stdout` and `stderr`. Add an env variable named PYTHONUNBUFFERED and set it to something (anything as long as its not empty). You can set it in the `env` block in the pod yaml or set it in the Docker image as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59812009/what-is-the-use-of-pythonunbuffered-in-docker-file)