Problems forcing python to flush print in console app
I have a console python program which does a bunch stuff analyzing excel documents. It works well but some of the operations take a long time and so I wanted to implement some progress bars for user convenience. I wrote this function:

def printProgress(message,value,finalvalue,length=40,mark="#",empty="-"):

    n = math.ceil(length * value / finalvalue)
    m = length - n

    text = message + f"[{mark*n}{empty*m}]"

    print(text,end='\r')

This function is called from within some of the longer loops in the program and it does work. But it only prints the bar once the process is complete so not really very useful.
I have tried using
    print(text,end='\r',flush=True)

and also placing
    sys.stdout.flush()

after the print statement. But to no-avail, I can't seem to get my bar to update in real time. I did test this function in a separate program where it was just called from a long loop with a sleep function in it and then it worked perfectly updating each iteration of the loop. But I don't want to introduce a sleep as that's just going to make my process even longer!
What am I missing here? I do know there are libraries available that do this but I'd like to understand why this code doesn't work.
I am running this on Python 3.7 in an Anaconda terminal on Windows 10.

flush=True should do what you want.

Try using a normal Command Prompt window instead of Anaconda. The Anaconda terminal may have its own buffering.

why not to use tqdm https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm

can you also include the structure of the longer loop? are you using some async calls in your loop by any chance?

@Barmar the anaconda command prompt is normal cmd and anaconda power shell is normal power shell, the only difference is that the conda activation script was run at startup to setup conda.

@VardanGrigoryants Quote from the question: "I do know there are libraries available that do this but I'd like to understand why this code doesn't work."

You may also need to set the PYTHONUNBUFFERED environment variable. https://stackoverflow.com/a/59812588/2449192 Note, this answer applies to Docker, but you can set it in your Anaconda terminal.
