# python script executes quicker in docker container than natively

Tags: python, docker

I am executing a simple python (v 2.7.17) script which finds the square roots of numbers between 1 - 1000000. it does this 1000000 times for a single execution. This is then repeated 100 times. The output is the time taken to execute each cycle.

When I execute this script in a Linux shell, each execution time is printed one after the other. They vary, but the average across the total 100 executions is `0.126154s`.

When I run the exact same script within a docker container, there is no output until the end of all 100 executions where the output for all 100 is displayed all at one. The execution times are quicker when compared to native an average of 100 docker executions is `0.095896s`.

When I apply various stresses to the system when executing the script both natively and in docker, the average execution times differ greatly. When I stress the CPU, I get an average across 100 executions of

```
native average 0.506660s
docker average 0.190208s
```

I am curious as to why my python script runs quicker when in a container. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated. Python code is:

```
import timeit 

mycode = """
def example(): 
        mylist = [] 
        for x in range(1000000): 
                mylist.append(sqrt(x)) 
"""

mysetup = "from math import sqrt"

print timeit.timeit(setup = mysetup,stmt = mycode,number = 1000000)
```

Comment: The execution time could be worse natively since it has to print each execution time.

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39486327/

Comment: I initially thought it was the print statement but when I remove that from the code the python-docker script still finishes quicker

Comment: Have you tried executing the function let's say 1000 times? Is the time linear for both?
Could be related to your native environment serving other processes and just postponing the calculation, or the spin-up time for the interpreter takes longer because of that?

Answer (score 0):

I did more digging and found out why I had better execution times whilst running the script in a container.

When I start the script in a container on my system (4 core) it looks like a whole core or a percentage of all four is dedicated or reserved to running that container, the rest of the systems running processes are then divided up with what CPU availability is left.

When running the script natively the script has to compete with everything else running on the system. So when I applied the stress tests (stress-ng) to the CPU - each stress test is a new process where the available processor time is dividied into equal amounts for each stress process. The more stresses I applied to the system the slower the script was executing but when executing in a container this did not apply due to a large chunk of processor available all the time to the container.